# PHP array_search trouble

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.5

```
$data = Array
(
    [68315163] => Donnie1
    [68328887] => Donnie1
    [68353339] => Donnie1
)
```

I want to get the all the keys for Donnie1 value it is showing only the first one

```
$datum = array_search('Donnie1', $data);

print_r($datum);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why is the title of your question "PHP array_column trouble" if you're not using that functionality at all?

Comment: have you tried `$data['68315163']` ?

Comment: can you rephrase the  question? please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`array_search()` does not return array. It only returns the first key.

`array_keys()` would be the correct function for this use. It returns an array of all keys with the given value.

```
$datum = array_keys($data, "Donnie1");
```

Answer (score 4):

`array_search()` does not search array keys. It only searches array values.

Getting this value is basic PHP:

```
$datum = $data['68315163'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_search('68315163', $data)` doesn't return anything useful because the value you're searching for is not in the array.

This function searches through the values, and returns the key at the found value.  Please see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
    (
        [68315163] => Donnie
        [68328887] => Donnie1
        [68353339] => Donnie2
    )
$datum = array_search('Donnie1', $data);

echo $datum;// return only value of given key: 68328887
```

You are passing wrong parameters to array_search(). you need to pass value of array then this function will return matching key;